# Why the absolute value of the max negative integer -2147483648 is still -2147483648?

Tags: c, libc

The result of `abs(-2147483648)` is `-2147483648`, isn't it?
it seems unacceptable.

```
printf("abs(-2147483648): %d\n", abs(-2147483648));
```

output:

```
abs(-2147483648): -2147483648
```

Comment: I believe this is undefined behavior. I don't have the C standard handy, so I cannot back it up.

Comment: What do you expect it to be, given that `abs(int)` returns an `int`?

Comment: Latest draft of C11 says (7.21.6.1, about abs and friends) "If the
result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined"

Comment: @PhilipKendall The absolute value can be a negative value?

Comment: linux man page says (man 3 abs): Trying to take the absolute value of the most negative integer is not defined.

Comment: You get the right value if int has more than 32 bits. But for 32 bit ints, what would you have it be, considering that 2147483648 cannot be represented in 32 bits?

Comment: @JimBalter technically it can not be represented in 31 bits. The sign bit is what's causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The standard says about `abs()`:

> The `abs`, `labs`, and `llabs` functions compute the absolute value of an integer `j`. If the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined.

And the result indeed cannot be represented because the 2's complement representation of signed integers isn't symmetric. Think about it... If you have 32 bits in an `int`, that gives you 2<sup>32</sup> distinct values from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`. That's an even number of values. So, if there's only one 0, the number of values greater than 0 cannot be the same as the number of values less than 0. And so there's no positive counterpart to `INT_MIN` with a value of -`INT_MIN`.

So, what's unacceptable is calling `abs(INT_MIN)` on your platform.

Answer (score 19):

Negative numbers are usually represented whit binary complement.

To convert positive to negative it is used logic

```
x -> not(x)+1
```

For 8 bits arithmetic

01111111b is 127 and -127 becomes
10000000b + 1 = 10000001b

and to opposite direction -127 
10000001b becomes
01111110b + 1 = 01111111b

What about -128?

-128 is 10000000b  and there is no positive counterpart of it, because there is no 128 in 8 bits signed arithmetic.

10000000 -> 01111111 + 1 = 10000000 and -128 again

Same applies to original question

Comment: that's why 0 and the minimum value are always the same after negating in two's complement

Answer (score 11):

Since 2147483648 is greater than `INT_MAX` on your implementation, then `abs(-2147483648)` is undefined.

Answer (score 5):

This is code in abs.c in GNU glibc source code.

```
/* Return the absolute value of I.  */
int
DEFUN(abs, (i), int i)
{
  return(i < 0 ? -i : i);
}
```

So,abs(-2147483648) return -(-2147483648) . In x86,it is implement by this two instruction

```
movl    $-2147483648, %eax
negl    %eax
```

negl instruction is implemented by this way:
num=0-num; 
sbb is implemented by this way:
Subtracts the source from the destination, and subtracts 1 extra if the Carry Flag is set.
So abs(-2147483648) (hex is 0x80000000 ) --> -(-2147483648) --> 0-(-2147483648)   becomes (0x80000000) finally.

details of negl instruction,please 
visit http://zsmith.co/intel_n.html#neg

details of sbb instruction ,please visit http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/sbb.html

Answer (score 1):

I recall that this is an overflow error. The maximum value of an integer in S2C for signed integers is -(2^(total bits - 1)). However the maximum positive value is actually (2^(total bits - 1))-1. Bitwise, the function produces the right thing. However, the "correct" bitwise value overshoots the maximum positive value by one, rolling over to the set of negative values.

Comment: This may be what happens for some implementations, but the Standard says that it is undefined behavior. Before C23 integers could be represented as two's complement, one's complement, or sign and magnitude. But even in C23 where only two's complement is allowed, it is still undefined behavior to attempt `abs(INT_MIN)`.

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
printf("abs(-2147483648): %u\n", abs(-2147483648));
```

Comment: This, my friend, has undefined behavior. You're printing a signed integer with the unsigned formatter. I -1 because it moreover does not answer the question.

Comment: The question is asking for explaining, not the way to fix the code.