# Why is -(-2147483648) = - 2147483648 in a 32-bit machine?

Tags: c, 32-bit, twos-complement

I think the question is self explanatory, I guess it probably has something to do with overflow but still I do not quite get it. What is happening, bitwise, under the hood?

Why does `-(-2147483648) = -2147483648` (at least while compiling in C)?

Comment: Note: the value of -INT_MIN is undefined in C.  I'd guess most implementations, most of the time, will return INT_MIN, but they don't have to.

Comment: It is UB, you are just seeing the behavior of the NEG instruction on Intel/AMD processors.  It is a lot more fun if you divide that number by -1.

Comment: It's usually more helpful to ask this type of question with Java tag, even if you intend to write C code.. increases the signal to noise ratio since there doesn't need to be an UB disclaimer on everything

Comment: Interview question: `abs(INT_MIN)==?`

Comment: it's the same in a 64-bit machine as well. It's the size of `int` that matters, not what machine are you on

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136761/discussion-on-question-by-lesscomfortable-why-is-2147483648-2147483648-i).

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc : On 16 bit machines though, you can't represent -2147483648 in `int`.

Comment: @MartinBonner please don't go beyond what the OP expected. He simply wants to know about 2's complement and he's on a "32-bit machine"

Comment: See https://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-range-of-the-integer-constant-between-32768-32767/answer/Dwayne-Towell for a similar question/answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the absolute value of the max negative integer -2147483648 is still -2147483648?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243014/why-the-absolute-value-of-the-max-negative-integer-2147483648-is-still-2147483)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

### Negating an (unsuffixed) integer constant:

The expression `-(-2147483648)` is perfectly defined in C, however it may be not obvious why it is this way.

When you write `-2147483648`, it is formed as unary minus operator applied to integer constant. If `2147483648` can't be expressed as `int`, then it s is represented as `long` or `long long`<sup>*</sup> (whichever fits first), where the latter type is guaranteed by the C Standard to cover that value<sup>†</sup>.

To confirm that, you could examine it by:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(-2147483648));
```

which yields `8` on my machine.

The next step is to apply second `-` operator, in which case the final value is `2147483648L` (assuming that it was eventually represented as `long`). If you try to assign it to `int` object, as follows:

```
int n = -(-2147483648);
```

then the actual behavior is *implementation-defined*. Referring to the Standard:

> #### C11 §6.3.1.3/3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.

The most common way is to simply cut-off the higher bits. For instance, GCC [documents](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) it as:

> For conversion to a type of width N, the value is reduced modulo 2^N
>   to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

Conceptually, the conversion to type of width 32 can be illustrated by bitwise AND operation:

```
value & (2^32 - 1) // preserve 32 least significant bits
```

In accordance with [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) arithmetic, the value of `n` is formed with all zeros and MSB (sign) bit set, which represents value of `-2^31`, that is `-2147483648`.

### Negating an `int` object:

If you try to negate `int` object, that holds value of `-2147483648`, then assuming two's complement machine, the program will exhibit *undefined behavior*:

```
n = -n; // UB if n == INT_MIN and INT_MAX == 2147483647
```

> #### C11 §6.5/5 Expressions
>
> If an *exceptional condition* occurs during the evaluation of an
>   expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or
>   not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior
>   is undefined.

#### Additional references:

- [INT32-C. Ensure that operations on signed integers do not result in overflow](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow#INT32-C.Ensurethatoperationsonsignedintegersdonotresultinoverflow-UnaryNegation)

---

<sup>*) In withdrawed C90 Standard, there was no `long long` type and the rules were different. Specifically, sequence for unsuffixed decimal was `int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int` (C90 §6.1.3.2 Integer constants).</sup>

<sup>†) This is due to `LLONG_MAX`, which must be at least `+9223372036854775807` (C11 §5.2.4.2.1/1).</sup>

Comment: This answer should emphasize that it only applies to integer literals; in particular, it does not apply to negating an `int` object containing the value `-2147483648`.

Comment: it's promoted to `long long` only in modern compilers (C99 or C++11 and later). On old compilers it'll give surprise results [Why it is different between -2147483648 and (int)-2147483648](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12620753/995714), [Casting minimum 32-bit integer (-2147483648) to float gives positive number (2147483648.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11536389/995714)

Comment: @Hurkyl Note that in C, `2147483648` is specified as an _integer constant_, not an integer literal.  Literals in C can have their address taken like _string literals_ and _compound literals_, unlike `2147483648`.

Comment: "implicitely promoted to long or long long* (which is guaranteed to cover that value†)"- what about `-9223372036854775808`?

Comment: @Random832: I think that this case alone deserves separate question, but in short take a look at [DR #298](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_298.htm). The bottom line is that it would likely result in _constraint violation_ (C11 §6.4.4/2), assuming that: 1) the `9223372036854775808` is not representable by `long long` type (so in fact, it exceeds `LLONG_MAX` ), 2) the implementation does not support extended integer types (e.g. GCC does not).

Comment: `2147483648` is not promoted to anything.  It has the type `int`, `long` or `long long` (whichever is the smallest it can fit in).  "promote" refers to a value which actually does have a type narrower than `int`,  being changed to a value of different type when used in an expression

Comment: @M.M: Corrected. I was using term "promoted" more informally, but you are right, that it should have been corrected, not to confuse with different aspects of the language.

Answer (score 16):

***Note: this answer does not apply as such on the obsolete ISO C90 standard that is still used by many compilers***

First of all, on C99, C11, the expression `-(-2147483648) == -2147483648` is in fact *false*:

```
int is_it_true = (-(-2147483648) == -2147483648);
printf("%d\n", is_it_true);
```

prints

```
0
```

---

So how it is possible that this evaluates to true?
The machine is using 32-bit [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integers. The `2147483648` is an integer constant that quite doesn't fit in 32 bits, thus it will be either `long int` or `long long int` depending on whichever is the first where it fits. This negated will result in `-2147483648` - and again, even though the number `-2147483648` can fit in a 32-bit integer, the expression `-2147483648` consists of a >32-bit positive integer preceded with unary `-`!

You can try the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(2147483647));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(2147483648));
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(-2147483648));
}
```

The output on such machine most probably would be 4, 8 and 8.

Now, `-2147483648` negated will again result in `+214783648`, which is still of type `long int` or `long long int`, and everything is fine.

*In C99, C11, the integer constant expression `-(-2147483648)` is well-defined on all conforming implementations.*

---

Now, when this value is assigned to a variable of type `int`, with 32 bits and two's complement representation, the value is not representable in it - the values on 32-bit 2's complement would range from -2147483648 to 2147483647.

The C11 standard [6.3.1.3p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p3) says the following of integer conversions:

> - [When] the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is **implementation-defined** or an **implementation-defined** signal is raised.

That is, the C standard doesn't actually define what the value in this case would be, or doesn't preclude the possibility that the execution of the program stops due to a signal being raised, but leaves it to the implementations (i.e. compilers) to decide how to handle it [(C11 3.4.1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.1):

> **implementation-defined behavior**
>
> unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made

and [(3.19.1)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.1p1):

> **implementation-defined value**
>
> unspecified value where each implementation documents how the choice is made

---

In your case, the implementation-defined behaviour is that the value is the 32 lowest-order bits [*]. Due to the 2's complement, the (long) long int value `0x80000000` has the bit 31 set and all other bits cleared. In 32-bit two's complement integers the bit 31 is the sign bit - meaning that the number is negative; all value bits zeroed means that the value is the minimum representable number, i.e. `INT_MIN`.

---

[*] GCC [documents its implementation-defined behaviour in this case as follows](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html):

> *The result of, or the signal raised by, converting an integer to a signed integer type when the value cannot be represented in an object of that type (C90 6.2.1.2, C99 and C11 6.3.1.3).*
>
> For conversion to a type of width `N`, the value is reduced modulo `2^N` to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a C question, for on a C implementation featuring 32-bit two's complement representation for type `int`, the effect of applying the unary negation operator to an `int` having the value `-2147483648` is **undefined**.  That is, the C language specifically disavows designating the result of evaluating such an operation.

Consider more generally, however, how the unary `-` operator is defined in two's complement arithmetic: the inverse of a positive number *x* is formed by flipping all the bits of its binary representation and adding `1`.  This same definition serves as well for any negative number that has at least one bit other than its sign bit set.

Minor problems arise, however, for the two numbers that have no value bits set: 0, which has no bits set at all, and the number that has only its sign bit set (-2147483648 in 32-bit representation).  When you flip all the bits of either of these, you end up with all value bits set.  Therefore, when you subsequently add 1, the result overflows the value bits.  If you imagine performing the addition as if the number were unsigned, treating the sign bit as a value bit, then you get

```
    -2147483648 (decimal representation)
-->  0x80000000 (convert to hex)
-->  0x7fffffff (flip bits)
-->  0x80000000 (add one)
--> -2147483648 (convert to decimal)
```

Similar applies to inverting zero, but in that case the overflow upon adding 1 overflows the erstwhile sign bit, too.  If the overflow is ignored, the resulting 32 low-order bits are all zero, hence -0 == 0.

Comment: I'm afraid Grzegorz Szpetkowski nailedl it: the expression `-(-2147483648)` is perfectly defined.

Comment: @chqrlie: Only if you assume the OP is talking about integral literals, rather than asking about what happens when you negate an `int` variable containing the value `-2147483648`.

Comment: It's perfectly defined, because [`-2147483648` is a `long long` in modern compilers and `unsigned long` in older ones](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8511877/995714). The results are different in either case but they're still defined

Comment: @chqrlie, you are correct, of course, but that's missing the point of the question.  I have reworded that portion of my answer to correct for that technicality.

Answer (score 2):

I'm gonna use a 4-bit number, just to make maths simple, but the idea is the same.

In a 4-bit number, the possible values are between 0000 and 1111. That would be 0 to 15, but if you wanna represent negative numbers, the first bit is used to indicate the sign (0 for positive and 1 for negative).

So 1111 is not 15. As the first bit is 1, it's a negative number. To know its value, we use the two-complement method as already described in previous answers: "invert the bits and add 1":

- inverting the bits: 0000
- adding 1: 0001

0001 in binary is 1 in decimal, so 1111 is -1.

The two-complement method goes both ways, so if you use it with any number, it will give you the binary representation of that number with the inverted sign.

Now let's see 1000. The first bit is 1, so it's a negative number. Using the two-complement method:

- invert the bits : 0111
- add 1: 1000 (8 in decimal)

So 1000 is -8. If we do `-(-8)`, in binary it means `-(1000)`, which actually means using the two-complement method in 1000. As we saw above, the result is also 1000.
So, in a 4-bit number, `-(-8)` is equals -8.

In a 32-bit number, `-2147483648` in binary is `1000..(31 zeroes)`, but if you use the two-complement method, you'll end up with the same value (the result is the same number).

That's why in 32-bit number `-(-2147483648)` is equals `-2147483648`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of C, the specifics of the implementation and whether we are talking about variables or literals values.

The first thing to understand is that there are no negative integer literals in C "-2147483648" is a unary minus operation followed by a positive integer literal.

Lets assume that we are running on a typical 32-bit platform where int and long are both 32 bits and long long is 64 bits and consider the expression.

(-(-2147483648) == -2147483648 )

The compiler needs to find a type that can hold 2147483648, on a comforming C99 compiler it will use type "long long" but a C90 compiler can use type "unsigned long".

If the compiler uses type long long then nothing overflows and the comparision is false. If the compiler uses unsigned long then the unsigned wraparound rules come into play and the comparision is true.

Answer (score -1):

For the same reason that winding a tape deck counter 500 steps forward from 000 (through 001 002 003 ...) will show 500, and winding it backward 500 steps backward from 000 (through 999 998 997 ...) will also show 500.

This is two's complement notation.  Of course, since 2's complement sign convention is to consider the topmost bit the sign bit, the result overflows the representable range, just like 2000000000+2000000000 overflows the representable range.

As a result, the processor's "overflow" bit will be set (seeing this requires access to the machine's arithmetic flags, generally not the case in most programming languages outside of assembler).  This is the *only* value which will set the "overflow" bit when negating a 2's complement number: any other value's negation lies in the range representable by 2's complement.