# How negation in C++ works？

Tags: c++

I don't know why the following code prints the same number. I expect it would give me some overflow error or something else.

```
int a = -2147483648;
int b = -a;
cout << a << "\t" << b << endl;
```

It prints `-2147483648   -2147483648`.

Comment: see [What is undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939). Anything can happen.

Comment: Negating the min int value with two's compliment arithmetic is undefined behavior but this is typical of the behavior of two's compliment math.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)

Comment: You are aware of the special attribute of that magic number, aren't you?

Comment: The problem with your code is that `int` has 32 bit only, in your case. Hence, the max. possible value is `2147483647`. `-2147483648` is the one and only value which cannot be negated. (Try this with `int64_t` instead of `int` and it will work.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the absolute value of the max negative integer -2147483648 is still -2147483648?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243014/why-the-absolute-value-of-the-max-negative-integer-2147483648-is-still-2147483)